# RSA with common modulus but different ciphertexts and public exponents

Tags: rsa

I have two different ciphertexts $c_1$ and $c_2$, and two different public keys that share the same modulus such that $e_1 \neq e_2$ but $n_1 = n_2$.

- What attack can I use to recover the private keys?
- Common modulus attack works only if $c_1 = c_2$, doesn't it?

Comment: This might be a homework question.

Comment: Obviously the question is about textbook RSA. Also, something must be known about the plaintext(s); such that: they are the same. Otherwise, $c_1$ and $c_2$ give no information and the only way is factoring $n_1$.

Comment: Actually, even with textbook RSA, there isn't a way to recover the private key, even if the messages were the same.  You could recover the common message (assuming $e_1, e_2$ are relatively prime), and that's a standard textbook attack...